# Prove the group of all real translations and all glide reflections with axis$R$ is isomorphic to $\{1,-1\}\times \mathbb R$

Tags: group-theory, isometry

> Let $G$ be the group of all isometries of $C$ consisting of all real translations, and all glide reflections with axis $\mathbb R$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $\{1,-1\} \times \mathbb R$.

I feel it difficult, first of all, to write down the group $G$. I think all real translations can be represented as $z \to z+b, \forall b \in \mathbb R$, but what is all glide reflections with axis $\mathbb R$?

Moreover, how can I show the two groups are isomorphic?

Comment: I was just about to ask this question, it seems your doing the exact same problem I am. Did you have any luck? It seems that it's intuitively true since you can let the $-1$ or $1$ indicate whether it's a glide reflection or not (respectively) and then the real number defines the amount it's translated. But I have no idea how to present it rigourously.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: glide reflections along the real axis are just compositions of translations along the real axis ($z \mapsto a + z$, where $a \in \Bbb{R}$) and complex conjugation ($z \mapsto z^*$).

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, I'll add what progress I made with this question. Though I'm not entirely sure how correct this is, so if anyone can see any mistakes please point them out.

---

What we want to do is show that there exists an isomorphism between $G$ and $\{-1,1\}\times \mathbb{R}$ which we can do by creating a function that connects the two groups: $\theta:G\mapsto \{-1,1\}\times \mathbb{R}$ with the property that:
$$ \forall a,b\in G \;\;\; \theta(a\circ b)=\theta(a)*\theta(b) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; [1] $$
where $*$ is defined: $(a_1,b_1)*(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,b_1+b_2)$ since $\{-1,1\}$ is a multiplicative group and $\mathbb{R}$ is an additive one.

The thing that confused me was how to represent the isometries in $G$. From the other answer it's clear that we can represent any element in $G$ as either $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ or $z\mapsto z+b$ (for some $b\in \mathbb{R}$ since both translations are alway in the direction of the real line) since it's either going to be a glide reflection or a translation.

To prove $[1]$ I tried to define $\theta$ using the above reasoning as follows:
$$ \forall a\in G \;\;\; \theta(a) = \begin{cases} (1,b) &\mbox{if translation }\\ 
(-1,b) & \mbox{if glide reflection}\end{cases} $$
now to interpret $\theta(a\circ b)$ you have to just consider the cases of what $a\circ b$ can be since it's just the composition of two isometries.  Since $a,b$ will be either $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ or $z\mapsto z+b$ it turns out that only two possibilies exist for their composition:  $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b+b'$ or $z\mapsto z+b+b'$. To illustrate let $a$ be $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ and $b$ be $z\mapsto z+b'$ so that $a\circ b$ would be $z\mapsto \overline{z+b'}+b$ which is the same as $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b+b'$ (since $b,b'\in \mathbb{R}$).

So if $a\circ b$ is $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b+b'$ then $\theta$ maps it to $(-1,b+b')$. The r.h.s of $[1]$ would be:
$$ \theta(a)*\theta(b)=(1,b)*(-1,b')=(-1,b+b') $$
which shows they are the same. It doesn't matter which was round you have $a$ or $b$ since $*$ and $\circ$ are commutative. Similarly for $z\mapsto z+b+b'$ would give $(1,b+b')$.

Then we just need to check that it's a bijection which seems intuitively clear. To show it's injective we can consider $\theta(x)=\theta(y)$ so means that $(\pm 1,b_x)=(\pm 1,b_y)$ and thus $b_x=b_y$ so they must be the same isometry and $x=y$. Surjection requires that $(\pm 1,b)$ is mapped to by an isometry in $G$ which it true since both $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ and $z\mapsto z+b$ are in $G$. Thus it's an isomorphism.

---

Hopefully that's sufficient to show it, even if it not very concise, I may have gone little over the top with it! Hopefully someone can check to make sure this a reasonable answer. When I asked this question [Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30382/servaes) said that a possible candidate for $\theta$ could be:
$$ \forall \varphi \in G \;\; \;\;\theta(\varphi)=(-i(\varphi(i)-\varphi(0)),\varphi(0))$$ which I thought was a much nicer way than the piecewise way that I took.