# Showing that $G$ is isomorphic to $\{1,-1\}\times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, isometry

Let $G$ be the group of all isometries of $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of all real translations, and all glide reflections with axis $\mathbb R$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $\{1,-1\} \times \mathbb R$.

---

This question has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523244/prove-the-group-of-all-real-translations-and-all-glide-reflections-with-axisr) but it hasn't had any answers yet and I wanted to add what I'd tried without taking over the other question. It seems that it's intuitively true since you can let the $−1$ or $1$ indicate whether it's a glide reflection or not (respectively) and then the real number defines the amount it's translated. I just can't turn that it into something rigorous.

It seems that we'd need to define $\theta:G\rightarrow \{-1,1\}\times \mathbb{R}$ and then we'd need to show that $$\forall a,b\in G \;\;\; \theta(a\circ b)=\theta(a)*\theta(b) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; [1]$$
where from intuition it seems we could then define $*$ by: 
$$ (a_1,b_1)*(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,b_1+b_2) $$
since, for example, if we compose two glide reflections (both across the same line) then it's clear that both reflections cancel out which corresponds to $(-1,b_1)*(-1,b_2)=(1,b_1+b_2)$. Then we can just add the translations.

So with that defined it seems that $[1]$ should be true since we have $a\circ b$,  which is just another element of $G$ (since it's a group), and so there must exist an element of $\{-1,1\}\times\mathbb{R}$ that it's mapped to by $\theta$. The R.H.S composes the two outside of $G$ but (hopefully) with the same effect.

The problem I have is I'm not sure if this is correct, and even if it is I'm not sure how to put this is a more compact and rigorous way (like, if it's correct, I'm not sure how you'd show that $\theta$ is a bijection between the two groups). Any pointers would be great! Thanks

---

EDIT - added further to comments:
since all $a$ will be either $z\mapsto z+b$ or $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ then:
$$\forall a\in G \;\;\; \theta(a) = \begin{cases} (1,b) &\mbox{translation }\\ 
(-1,b) & \mbox{glide reflection}\end{cases} $$

Comment: You want to show that $\theta$ is an isomorphism. To do so, a good start would be to give a formal description of $G$. What do its elements look like, and what does the group operation do with them?

Comment: @Servaes this is what's not too clear to me since it seems we can define a translation along $\mathbb{R}$ to be $z\mapsto z+b$ for some real $b$. Now in the book he defines glide reflections to be maps of the form $z\mapsto a\bar{z}+b$ with $a\bar{b}+b\neq 0$ so in this case I think it would just be $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b'$ for some $b'$. I just can't see how to use that with my reasoning above in a rigorous way.

Comment: You could identify the complex plane with $\Bbb{R}^2$, identifying $z=x+yi$ with the pair $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$. Then $z\ \longmapsto\ z+b$ becomes $(x,y)\ \longmapsto\ (x+b,y)$ and $z\ \longmapsto\ \overline{z}$ becomes $(x,y)\ \longmapsto\ (x,-y)$.

Comment: @Servaes That makes sense. How could we define $\theta$ since it would seem that  $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ should output $(-1,0)$ and that $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ would give $(-1,b)$ and $z\mapsto z+b$ as $(1,b)$ etc. I'm not sure how to get an explicit formula for $\theta$ though.  Thanks

Comment: There are many ways. For example, for $\varphi\in G$ set
$$\theta(\varphi):=(-i(\varphi(i)-\varphi(0)),\varphi(0)).$$
Here my $\varphi(0)$ is the same as your $b$.

Comment: @Servaes that's a really neat way! I wouldn't have thought of that. The way I was thinking was to do it piecewise like I've edited into my answer. Would that be an okay way to define $\theta$? Even if is not very elegant! Thanks

Comment: That works too, as long as you can still show it's a group homomorphism.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for the help! I've had a quick sketch through using the piecewise definition. Hopefully I can show it, there are just cases to consider. For example if $a$ is $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ and $b$ is $z\mapsto z+b'$  so that composing them would give $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b+b'$ then we'd have $\theta(a\circ b)=(-1,b+b')$. $\theta(a)*\theta(b)=(-1,b)*(1,b')=(-1,b+b')$ and similarly for when $\theta(a\circ b)=(1,b+b')$. Then I just need to show that it's a bijection.

Comment: @Servaes which I could maybe show by proving it's injective since $\theta(x)=\theta(y)$ which means that $(\pm 1,b_x)=(\pm 1,b_y)$ so that $b_x=b_y$ so that they must be the same isometries so $x=y$. Then to prove that it's surjective we need to show that there exists $a\in G :(\pm 1 ,b)=\theta(a)$ which would make sense since $(\pm 1, b)$ is either $z\mapsto \bar{z}+b$ or $z\mapsto z+b$ both of which are in $G$. Does that look about right?

Comment: There is no good reason for deliberately asking a duplicate question. If you have ideas for a solution, then post them as comments or a partial answer for the original question.

Comment: @RobArthan if what I've done is correct I'll delete this question and then add it as an answer to the other question. I didn't want to take over it since I didn't know whether what I was doing was correct.

Comment: @Jay: yes, that's a good plan.